# How to split SASH from in SWT?

Tags: java, swt

I created an application with two parts :

```
      1. tree viewer
      2. table viewer + messages
```

it look like

```
                 -------------------------------
                 -   tree    -         table   -   
                 -           -                 -
                 -           - -----------------             
                 -           -    messages             
                 -------------------------------
```

I tried to build Sash from thaty will split the tree area and the table + message area.
Then I want to split the table area to two area table and messages.

I got error message when I tried to do the second split of table and message.

This is the code

```
  SashForm sashForm = new SashForm(parent, SWT.HORIZONTAL);
    Composite treeComposite = new Composite(sashForm, SWT.BORDER);
    Composite detailsCompositePart = new Composite(sashForm, SWT.BORDER);

    GridLayout parentSideGridLayout = new GridLayout();
    parentSideGridLayout.numColumns = 1;
    detailsCompositePart.setLayout(parentSideGridLayout);

    sashForm.setWeights(new int[] { 300, 700 });
    createTreePart(treeComposite )

    SashForm verticalForm = new SashForm(detailsCompositePart, SWT.VERTICAL);
    verticalForm.setWeights(new int[] { 800, 200 });

    detailsComposite = new Composite(sashForm, SWT.BORDER);
                createDeatilsPart(detailsComposite )
    messageComposite = new Composite(sashForm, SWT.NONE);
             createMessagePart(messageComposite )
```

I got error message after this statment

```
        verticalForm.setWeights(new int[] { 800, 200 });
```

"Argument not valid" when i tried to do the second shash
Could you advise me How i can fix this issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting that error, because `verticalForm` doesn't have two children. You have to replace `sashForm` in the constructor of the two `Composite`s with `verticalForm`:

```
SashForm verticalForm = new SashForm(detailsCompositePart, SWT.VERTICAL);

detailsComposite = new Composite(verticalForm , SWT.BORDER);
createDeatilsPart(detailsComposite);
messageComposite = new Composite(verticalForm , SWT.NONE);
createMessagePart(messageComposite);

verticalForm.setWeights(new int[] { 800, 200 });
```